# why this user control is not bind correctly in wpf (using caliburn micro)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, caliburn.micro

I have a user control that I placed it on another user control as follow:

```
<Grid>
    <Control:ViewerControl  x:Name="ViewerControl" />
</Grid>
```

and in VM I have:

```
public ImageSourceViewModel()
{
    this.ViewerControl = new ViewerControl();

}

#endregion

#region Public Properties

/// <summary>
/// Gets the viewer control.
/// </summary>
public ViewerControl ViewerControl { get; private set; }
```

But it is not bindded.

I also tested this and did not get the correct result:

```
<Grid>
    <Control:ViewerControl  DataContext="{Binding ViewerControl}" />
</Grid>
```

The reason that I think it is not bind correctly is as follow:

To test that it is binded correctly, I placed a textblock on ViewerControl as follow:

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  Foreground="Blue"  x:Name="TextData" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

and in ViewerControl contructor I have:

```
public ViewerControl()
{
   TextData.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();   
}

public
```

and I changed VM so it sets TextData to a new value as follow:

```
public ImageSourceViewModel()
{
    this.ViewerControl = new ViewerControl();
    ViewerControl.TextData.Text = "test";
}
```

If the viewer control bind correctly, I should see the test on screen but I am still seeing the time. so it is not bind correctly.

I am using Caliburn micro but the control which is written by somebody else is not using caliburn micro.

Comment: if you do mvvm you should NOT have a usercontrol in your vm. you should use  eg a Datatemplate to connect a datatype(viewmodel) to your view(usercontrol)

Answer (score 0):

You must be very confused about data binding because you are trying to data bind your `UserControl` to another instance of your `UserControl`:

```
<Control:ViewerControl DataContext="{Binding ViewerControl}" />
```

...

```
ViewerControl = new ViewerControl();
```

In WPF, we data bind *data* elements to *UI elements*, so your problem has nothing to do with Caliburn and I'd really recommend that you learn to use WPF properly before you add a further level of complexity (Caliburn). Please refer to the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further help with understanding data binding.

Comment: I did not get what you mean! I have a user control on my View that I want to bind it to a class on my ViewModel. how Can I do this?

Comment: @mans you post the usercontrol in your view and in your viewmodel. thats not the way you should do it